# how to do conditional copy, paste in one sheet to another sheet

Tags: vba

I appreciate if you help me to solve the below query. I want to do conditional copy from sheet 1 and paste in sheet 2. For example sheet 1 has two Cells in two Rows these two Cells data has to paste in single Cell in sheet 2 i.e which cell value is high that entire row data has to paste in sheet 2.

```
Sub UpdateData()
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, WsRR As Worksheet, WsRRAT As Worksheet
    Dim LrowWsRR As Long, LrowWsRRAT As Long
    Dim i As Long, n As Long

    n = 5

    Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input")
    Set WsRR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Running RC202")
    Set WsRRAT = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dossier Evaluation Template")

    LrowWsRR = WsRR.Range("A" & WsRR.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    With WsRR
        For i = 1 To 12
            .Cells(LrowWsRR, i).Value = wsI.Range("E" & n).Value
            n = n + 2
        Next i

        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 1).Value = wsI.Range("E6").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 2).Value = wsI.Range("E8").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 3).Value = wsI.Range("E10").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 4).Value = wsI.Range("E12").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 5).Value = wsI.Range("E14").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 6).Value = wsI.Range("E16").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 7).Value = wsI.Range("E18").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 8).Value = wsI.Range("E20").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 9).Value = wsI.Range("E22").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 10).Value = wsI.Range("E24").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 11).Value = wsI.Range("E26").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 12).Value = wsI.Range("E28").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 13).Value = wsI.Range("E30").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 14).Value = wsI.Range("E32").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 15).Value = wsI.Range("K8").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 15).Value = wsI.Range("K10").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 16).Value = wsI.Range("M8:M10").Value 'Here I want to do conditional copy paste
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 17).Value = wsI.Range("P8:P11").Value 'Here I want to do conditional copy paste

        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 18).Value = wsI.Range("K12:K14").Value 'Here I want to do conditional copy paste

        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 19).Value = wsI.Range("M12").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 19).Value = wsI.Range("K14").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 20).Value = wsI.Range("P12:P14").Value 'Here I want to do conditional copy paste

        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 21).Value = wsI.Range("K16").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 22).Value = wsI.Range("M16").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 23).Value = wsI.Range("P16").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 24).Value = wsI.Range("K18").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 25).Value = wsI.Range("M18").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 26).Value = wsI.Range("P18").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 27).Value = wsI.Range("K20:K26").Value 'Here I want to do conditional copy paste

        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 28).Value = wsI.Range("M20:M26").Value 'Here I want to do conditional copy paste

        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 29).Value = wsI.Range("P20:P26").Value 'Here I want to do conditional copy paste

        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 30).Value = wsI.Range("M30").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 31).Value = wsI.Range("M32").Value
        .Cells(LrowWsRR, 32).Value = wsI.Range("M34").Value
    End With   

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each of the rows you have commented, try this:

```
.Cells(LrowWsRR, 16).Value = Application.Max(wsI.Range("M8:M10").Value)
```

Simply add Excel's Max function to do the work for you.